# My webbpage is scrolling down when loaded in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I just started building a website from scratch and encountered a weird bug in firefox where it scrolls down the page to the first div and skipping its margin. 
I am **not** asking for a fix in firefox. I'm just asking for help finding an workaround. 
I already tried to set all possible scroll values to 0 using javascript with no luck. I think the problem is created by my weird constelation of divs but I'm not shure how exactly and how to fix it (obviously).
For reproduction I'm using firefox 88.01 (latest 26.05.21)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Demo - Start</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets.css">
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            load();
        }
        window.onresize = function () {
            resize();

        }
        function resize() {
            document.getElementById("foreground").style.height = window.innerHeight - document.getElementById("titlebar").offsetHeight + "px";
            document.getElementById("foreground").style.top = document.getElementById("titlebar").offsetHeight + "px";
            document.getElementById("background").style.top = document.getElementById("titlebar").offsetHeight + "px";
            document.getElementById("titlebar").style.paddingLeft = ((document.getElementById("body").offsetWidth - (document.getElementById("title_element_1").offsetWidth + document.getElementById("title_element_2").offsetWidth + document.getElementById("title_element_3").offsetWidth + document.getElementById("title_element_4").offsetWidth)) / 2 + "px");
        }
        function load() {
            resize();
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <div id="titlebar">
        <a id="title_element_1" class="active" href="#start">Start</a>
        <a id="title_element_2" href="#tour">Tour</a>
        <a id="title_element_3" href="#details">Details</a>
        <a id="title_element_4" href="#darkmode">Darkmode</a>
    </div>

    <div id="foreground">
        <div id="start" class="content">
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
        </div>

        <div id="end" class="content">
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
            <p>Demo text . . .</p>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 100px;">

        </div>

    </div>
    <img id="background" src="background.png" alt="Background">
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: gray;
}
#titlebar {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#titlebar a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    float: left;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
}
#titlebar a:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: black;        
}
#titlebar a.active {
    background-color: grey;
    color: black;  
}
#titlebar a.active:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: black; 
}
#background {
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#foreground {
    z-index: 1;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-color: #555555 #333;  
}
.content {
    padding: 50px;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.9);
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
#start {
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
}
#end {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't happen to me. Are you sure you're not on `whatever.html#start`?

Comment: actually you are right. why does that happen when on a site with # on it?

Comment: In this case, it's telling the browser to jump to the element with `id="start"` (*or* `<a name="start">` but that's so old-school that nobody mentions it anymore). It's called *hash* and can be used for navigation within the same document. You can also read the hash value and listen to hash changes from JS to create things like single page apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the start and end ID's to subclasses of content and for some reason it fixed it. I will close the question.